# Mven build - PKIX path building failed

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am getting the following error, When I run "mvn clean install" in the terminal.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (validate) on project test-dependencies: Failed during checkstyle execution: Failed to load suppressions file from: /Users/test/Documents/Team/workspace/test/test-dependencies/target/checkstyle-suppressions.xml: Unable to read /Users/test/Documents/Team/workspace/test/test-dependencies/target/checkstyle-suppressions.xml: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

The file does exist and I am able to access it.

The build runs fine when I skip checkstyle.

> mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true

Not sure how to triage this. Any help?

Comment: if you use the `-X` flag you'll get debug output which should shed some light on what it trying to be called. Potentially your java version needs updated to get the latest security updates, or an internal or self signed cert might be needed if you;re going through a proxy. 


`mvn -X clean install`

Comment: a wild guess: what is your checkstyle version? and what is the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration of your checkstyle-*.xml(s) ?

Comment: How did you set the configLocation parameter? Please post your configuration.